# C# - Listbox - Can the Listbox vertical height grow automatically?

Tags: c#

I want to select a number of files using OpenDialog and display them in a listbox.  If I have more file paths than can fit in the listbox, I'd like the list box to automatically grow vertically to fit all of the filenames.

How can this be done, please?  Thank you for your help.

```
foreach (string FileName in oOpenDialog.FileNames)
{
   //lstbx_Box1.IntegralHeight = false;  //This doesn't auto-grow the list box.
   lstbx_Box1.Items.Add(Path.GetFullPath(FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you can, since the height of listbox when having a single value is `21` you can add 21 for the height of listbox when a new item is added.

```
foreach (string FileName in oOpenDialog.FileNames)
{
   lstbx_Box1.Height += 21;
   lstbx_Box1.Items.Add(Path.GetFullPath(FileName));
}
```